# \citetitle{} without definite article

Tags: biblatex

I have the following cite:

```
\citet{vonNeumann1947} introduced expected utility theory, the first fully formalized theory of choice under risk, in their \citetitle{vonNeumann1947}.
```

where `vonNeumann1947` is defined as follows

```
@book{vonNeumann1947,
address = {Princeton},
author = {von Neumann, John and Morgenstern, Oskar},
booktitle = {The Theory of Games and Economic Behavior},
publisher = {Princeton University Press},
title = {{The Theory of Games and Economic Behavior}},
year = {1947}
}
```

This gets rendered by `biblatex` as

```
von Neumann and Morgenstern (1947) introduced expected utility theory, the first fully formalized theory of choice under risk, in their The Theory of Games and Economic Behavior.
```

Is there any way of dropping the `The` from the book's title in the `\titlecite{}` without having to mess with the title in the `.bib` file?

Comment: Do you also use Biber as backend?

Comment: `in their book \citetitle{vonNeumann147}.`

Comment: @moewe Sorry, yes!

Comment: May I ask why you have both the `title` and `booktitle` fields in your entry. As far as I can see, you can drop the `booktitle` field.

Comment: Is there any reason for double-bracing the `title` field here? It is usually better to use title case and protect only those words that must not be lower-cased under any circumstances. With `biblatex` it is quite easy to turn off sentence casing if the style enables it (as `biblatex-apa` does for example). Note that in your use case I would probably go for writing the title manually and not rely on `biblatex`'s commands though I can see why it is appealing to do so.

Answer (score 1):

With Biber that could be as easy as

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=false]{
      \step[fieldsource=title, match=\regexp{\AThe\s+(.*)}, final]
      \step[fieldset=shorttitle, fieldvalue={$1}]
    }
  }
}
```

But because you have another pair of braces around the `title` field we need to take care of that with the slightly longer

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=false]{
      \step[fieldsource=title, match=\regexp{\AThe\s+(.*)}, final]
      \step[fieldset=shorttitle, fieldvalue={$1}]
    }
    \map[overwrite=false]{
      \step[fieldsource=title, match=\regexp{\A\{The\s+(.*)\}}, final]
      \step[fieldset=shorttitle, fieldvalue=\regexp{{$1}}]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In `biblatex-examples.bib` many entries having titles starting with "The" have manual `shorttitle` fields.